# XML axis properties do not support late binding

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-xml

Im having a problem with the XML in this function and many functions like it.

Error

XML axis properties do not support late binding.

Namespace

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Linq
```

Function

```
Public Shared Function get_intro(ByVal root_folder As String) As String
    Dim content As String = ""
    Dim docXML = XDocument.Load(root_folder & print_shop_doc)
    Dim intro_doc = From doc In docXML...<d:printshopdoc> _
            Select New With {.intro = doc.<d:intro>.Value}
    content = "<p" & no_indent & ">" & intro_doc(0).intro & "</p>" & vbCrLf
    Return content
End Function

docXML...<d:printshopdoc>
```

seems to be where the error is occurring and I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does putting an XML namespace declaration `Imports <xmlns:d="http://example.com/">` (where instead of `http://example.com/` you put the namespace URI used in the input XML) fix the problem?

Comment: Good news, that seems to have done it but now I'm getting a 403 error saying the file is denied.  I believe it has something to do with the

The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Access to the path 'local path' is denied..

error that I'm getting